# Ubuntu 14.04 Server + Nginx + stub_status module

Tags: 14.04, apt, nginx

I would like to know how to install the `stub_status` module on an already installed Nginx server via apt-get repository.

Do you know if this is an available feature? I have read that this module is not provided by default (official Nginx page) and it needs to be compiled manually.

Thanks,

Comment: To find out on your Ubuntu run `sudo apt-cache search stub_status` if it's there you'll see it in the generated list.

Comment: Hi @George - Thanks for your suggestion. I already tried it, but I cannot see this package, the output returns no content.:
```
ubuntu@websrv:~$ apt-cache search stub_status
ubuntu@websrv:~$
```
Any other idea?

Comment: That means it not available for you Ubuntu version.

Comment: Glad it went well. all the best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now *stub status* is used to determine the health of *nginx* via a *status* page. To use it your *nginx* must have been compiled with  **HttpStubStatusModule module**. To check if it was run this in the console:

`nginx -V 2>&1 | grep -o with-http_stub_status_module`

and if you get this output:

`with-http_stub_status_module`

then its installed.

**Setup based on nginx status:**

1. Installed:

   - create this file: `/etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/APPNAME.d/nginx_status.conf`
   - add this:

     ```
     location /nginx_status {
       stub_status on;
       access_log   off;
       allow 1.1.1.1; <--- [your machine IP address]
       deny all;
     }
     ```
   - reload *nginx* : `sudo service nginx-sp restart`
   - visit: `http://example.com/nginx_status`

     - you should see an output like this:

       ```
       Active connections: 43 
       server accepts handled requests
        7368 7368 10993 
       Reading: 0 Writing: 5 Waiting: 38
       ```
     - interpretation:

       - *Active connections* – Number of all open connections. This doesn’t mean number of users. A single user, for a single pageview can open many concurrent connections to your server.
       - *Server accepts handled requests* – This shows three values.

         - First is total accepted connections.
         - Second is total handled connections. Usually first 2 values are same.
         - Third value is number of and handles requests. This is usually greater than second value.
         - Dividing third-value by second-one will give you number of requests per connection handled by Nginx. In above example, 10993/7368, 1.49 requests per connections.
         - Reading – nginx reads request header
         - Writing – nginx reads request body, processes request, or writes response to a client
         - Waiting – keep-alive connections, actually it is `active – (reading + writing)`.
2. Not installed:

   - There are two options in installing

     - from launchpad:

       ```
       sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
       sudo apt-get update 
       sudo apt-get install nginx
       ```
     - from nginx package in Ubuntu repo:

       ```
       sudo apt-get install nginx-full
       ```
     - **Then follow steps in (1) above.**

Sources:

[Enabling nginx](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-enable-nginx-http-stub-status-module.html)

[Installing nginx](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-php-mysql-nginx-postfix/#installing-nginx)

[Extra reading](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-enable-nginx-http-stub-status-module.html)

Comment: Excellent how-to tutorial @George, many many thanks for your time! It worked as expected and now I can get those stats. Thanks!